# Can I safely remove Report.ashx file?

Tags: reporting

I am on Sitecore XP 8.0.0 and found Report.ashx file in the `/sitecore/shell/ClientBin/Reporting/` folder.

Can I safely remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The `Report.ashx` file is no longer used and can safely be removed.**

This file was used to drive the Executive Insight Dashboard that was deprecated in `8.0 Initial Release`.

For `Sitecore XP 8.0.0` - `Sitecore XP 8.2.7`, remove the `Report.ashx` file from `/sitecore/shell/ClientBin/Reporting/` folder from all your server instances.

For `Sitecore XP 7.5.0` - `Sitecore XP 7.5.2` see the description here:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000776